# ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal>" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

According to this procedure the cursor will shows two rows, but when i execute this query, it shows ERROR:  cursor "unnamed portal" does not exist
In image table

```
CREATE TABLE image
(
  id numeric(9,0) NOT NULL,
  nm_code character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  synonym text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT synonym_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
INSERT INTO image(
            id, nm_code, synonym)
    VALUES (01,'13160101','CAR TYRE');
INSERT INTO image(
                id, nm_code, synonym)
        VALUES (01,'10000101','CAR TYRE');
```

Legacy master table

```
CREATE TABLE legacymaster
(
  legacy_code character varying(20),
  source_data text,
)

insert into legacymaster (legacy_code,source_data) values ('123','WITH CAR TYRE FROM AUDI 2000')
```

mm_nounmodmaster table structure

```
CREATE TABLE mm_nounmodmaster
(
  nm_code character varying(18) NOT NULL,
  noun character varying(35),
  modifier1 character varying(35) NOT NULL,
  modifier2 character varying(35),
  modifier3 character varying(35),
  nm_type character(1) NOT NULL,
  nm_abbr character varying(200),
  nm_description character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  is_template character(1) DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
  )


    INSERT INTO mm_nounmodmaster(nm_code, noun, modifier1, modifier2, modifier3, nm_type, nm_abbr, 
            nm_description,is_template)
    VALUES ("10000101","ABRASIVE","--","--","","F","--","ABRASIVE",'Y')

    INSERT INTO mm_nounmodmaster(nm_code, noun, modifier1, modifier2, modifier3, nm_type, nm_abbr, 
                nm_description,is_template)
                VALUES ("13160101","TYRE","AUTOMOBILE","--","","F","TYR,AUTO","TYRE,AUTOMOBILE",'Y')
    INSERT INTO mm_nounmodmaster(nm_code, noun, modifier1, modifier2, modifier3, nm_type, nm_abbr, 
            nm_description,is_template)
            VALUES ("10020101","ACTUATOR","ELECTRICAL","--","--","F","ACTR,ELE","ACTUATOR,ELECTRICAL",'Y')
```

in nounmodmaster table three records are inserted but in image table synonyms contains 'car tyre' is only two nm_codes. So when i execute this function cursor will execute two rows in nounmodmaster except last row because it doesn't match with image table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_source_based_nounmod(legacy_code_in character varying)
                  RETURNS refcursor AS
                $BODY$
                    declare 
                        source text;
                        nmcode character varying(50);
                        v_parent_Rec1 record;
                        v_parent_Rec2 record;
                        item_desc character varying(50);
                        noun_t character varying(50);
                        mod1 character varying(50);
                        CUR REFCURSOR;
                begin
                    --select source_data into source from legacymaster where source_data=legacy_code_in;
                    raise notice '1';
                    for v_parent_Rec1 in(SELECT id,nm_code,synonym FROM image)loop
                raise notice '2';
                        --if exists (select source_data from legacymaster where legacy_code=legacy_code_in) then
                raise notice '3';
                        IF exists (select source_data from legacymaster where legacy_code=legacy_code_in and source_data ilike '%'||v_parent_Rec1.synonym||'%') THEN
                raise notice '4';
                            FOR v_parent_Rec2 IN(SELECT DISTINCT AA.NM_CODE, NM_TYPE,
                        (CASE WHEN NM_ABBR IS NOT NULL THEN NM_ABBR ELSE '--' END) as NM_ABBR,
                        NM_DESCRIPTION, NM_CATEGORY,
                        (CASE WHEN image.NM_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'INACTIVE' END) as STATUS,
                        (CASE WHEN NOUN IS NOT NULL AND NOUN <> '--' AND trim(both ' ' from NOUN) <> '' THEN NOUN ELSE '' END) || 
                        (CASE WHEN MODIFIER1 IS NOT NULL AND MODIFIER1 <> '--' AND TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM MODIFIER1) <> '' THEN ',' || MODIFIER1 ELSE '' END) ||
                        (CASE WHEN MODIFIER2 IS NOT NULL AND MODIFIER2 <> '--' AND TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM MODIFIER2) <> '' THEN ',' || MODIFIER2 ELSE '' END) ||
                        (CASE WHEN MODIFIER3 IS NOT NULL AND MODIFIER3 <> '--' AND TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM MODIFIER3) <> '' THEN ',' || MODIFIER3 ELSE '' END) AS NOUNMOD,
                        is_template, Count(image.nm_code) AS CountOfnm_code from mm_nounmodmaster aa
                            inner join image on image.nm_code=aa.nm_code
                            where image.synonym =v_parent_Rec1.synonym and image.nm_code=v_parent_Rec1.nm_code group by aa.nm_code,image.nm_code)LOOP

                    --raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.noun;
                    --raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.modifier1;
                        END LOOP;
                        ITEM_DESC:=v_parent_Rec1.nm_code;
                    raise notice '%',ITEM_DESC;
                    raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.nm_code;
                    raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.NM_TYPE;
                    raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.NM_ABBR;
                    raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.NM_DESCRIPTION;
                    raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.NM_CATEGORY;
                    raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.NOUNMOD;
                    raise notice '%',v_parent_Rec2.CountOfnm_code;
                        --end if;
                        OPEN CUR FOR 
                    SELECT DISTINCT v_parent_Rec2.nm_code,v_parent_Rec2.NM_TYPE,v_parent_Rec2.NM_ABBR,v_parent_Rec2.NM_DESCRIPTION,v_parent_Rec2.NM_CATEGORY,v_parent_Rec2.NOUNMOD,v_parent_Rec2.CountOfnm_code;
                    close cur;
                        end if;
                        end loop;
                  raise notice '5';
                RETURN CUR;
                    end;
                $BODY$
```

By passing Legacy_code_in parameter, it is in legacymaster table, if source data string contains  'Car Tyre'. then it will show two rows compare with image table

i need

Comment: It is unclear what that code it trying to do, and we cannot run it because we don't have the definition for the referenced tables. You open a cursor for a query without a table, then close it, then return it. Huh? How should that work? Do you get the error when you call the function? How do you call it?

Comment: I am  passing legacy code_in, it is in  legacy master table 
in legacy master table if source data string contains 'Car Tyre' then it will shows the two rows, why because in image table two rows are contains 'Car Tyre' string by using cursor it is possible.

Comment: I cannot see a `CREATE TABLE` statement or a `SELECT` statement here.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe now pls check it.

Comment: Still lacking `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` for `legacymaster` and `mm_nounmodmaster` (I don't feel like copying data from an image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the error you are getting is because, unless you specifically give the cursor a name, postgres returns a cursor with the special name "unnamed portal" and it can go on 1, 2, 3 etc.

This is fairly unhelpful generally, but fortunately there is an easy alternative.  You simply pass the cursor in as a parameter to the function, so your procedure will start:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_source_based_nounmod(legacy_code_in character varying, cur refcursor)
```

Assuming you are calling this function from a query window you can now have code that looks like:

```
BEGIN;
select func_source_based_nounmod('123', 'mycursor');
FETCH ALL IN "mycursor";
COMMIT;
```

Unfortunately that is the easy bit!  Given the data you posted, which BTW was incorrectly formatted and missing columns in your function, you will see that I passed in not 'Car Tyre' as you seemed to suggest but '123'.  This was necessary because otherwise you never get to open the cursor, because you have

```
IF exists (select source_data from legacymaster 
where legacy_code=legacy_code_in and
```

So legacy_code_in has to match the code in legacymaster.

Then your problems get worse.

You have a Count() in your following SELECT (FOR v_parent_Rec2 IN(SELECT DISTINCT AA.NM_CODE, NM_TYPE, etc.).  This means that all items in the SELECT need to be in the Group BY not just some of them!  Here I had a particular problem getting your code to run, as your table structure above was missing category.

Finally all this is in a loop.  At the end of this loop you open and close the cursor.  You seem to be under the misapprehension that doing so, you will be able to fill the cursor with successive rows.  This is not how it works.

Similarly you then return the cursor after you have closed it (hence the original error message).  In order to be able to access the cursor, the cursor needs to be open when you return it.

So how do you fix all this?  My recommendation is for you to use a temporary table.  Clear the table before calling the function.  Instead of opening and closing the cursor at the end of your loop, simply adds row to the temporary table.  And then after running the function read from the table.  If you need to have the resultset in a cursor, you can simply open the cursor on the temporary table.